# How can I flatten a nested formGroups in angular

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have a nested formGroup like this:

```
 generalFG= new FormGroup({
    firstFG : new FormGroup({
      AA: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      BB: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    }),
    secondFG : new FormGroup({
      CC: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,]),
      DD: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,])
     
  });
```

and I want to flatten them into one fromGroup , This is the desired result:

```
  generalFG= new FormGroup({
      AA: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      BB: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      CC: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,]),
      DD: new FormControl('', [Validators.required,])     
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote like this code and it works nice:

```
 addControlsRange(formGroupName: string, formJoin: any): any {
    Object.keys(this.generalFG.get(formGroupName).controls).forEach(key => {
      var vRes = this.generalFG.get(formGroupName).controls[key];
      formJoin.addControl(key, vRes);
    });
    return formJoin;
  }

  initGeneralFG(): void {
    var formJoin: FormGroup=new FormGroup(this.generalFG.get('firstFG').controls);
    formJoin=this.addControlsRange('secondFG',formJoin);
    formJoin=this.addControlsRange('thirdFG',formJoin);
    this.generalFG = formJoin;
}
```